# java thread not going out of scope

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Let me try to explain problem as much as I can. I have a main class, from this main class, i create a socket reader/writer. I then create a Reader 'runnable' and start the thread using threadmanager.

```
// MainApp.java

    public class MainApp{
            public static void main (String[] args){
                      MainApp app = new MainApp();
                      app.setUpNetworking();
                    }

            public void setUpNetworking(){
               try{// try socket conn
                  ThreadManager();
                  }catch{ //catch errors}}

            public void ThreadManager(){
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new ProcessMessage());
                t1.start();}

            public class ProcessMessage implements Runnable{
                public void run() {
                String message;// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{

                while((message=reader.readLine()) != null){

                    // read line from buffer
                                System.out.println(message)"
                    HandleMessage(message);

                }


                    } catch{}

                    }}

            public void HandleMessage(String message){System.out.println(message);}
            public void LoadGUI(){//load GUI, menubar, etc.


menuBarSubItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

            AdditionalFunction d = new AdditionalFunction(reader,writer);
        }
    });}
                    }
```

So far everything works. Now in LoadGUI() I create a Jframe, load and add a jmenubar, and add a few menu bar items. I create a actionlistener for menu bar items which I use to load another class (so basically, click menu bar item, a new jframe loads AdditionalFunction(reader,writer))

```
// AdditionalFunction.java

public class AdditionalFunction  {
public AdditionalFunction(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer){
ThreadManager();
    }


    public void ThreadManager(){

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ProcessDifferentMessage());
        t1.start();
    }

    public class ProcessDifferentMessage implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            String message;


            try{

                while((message=r.readLine()) != null){

                    System.out.println(message);
                    HandleDifferentMessage();


                }

            } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

        }

    }
    }
```

In this new frame, (call it AdditionalFunction.java) I pass the BufferedReader and writer I created in the Main class.

I then  create a threadmanager and try to run a thread (call it ProcessDifferentMessage() ) from the new frame(ie. AdditionalFunction.java, much like i did within the original main application).

(so at this point I should have two threads running.. one focusing on only reading ProcessMessage() and the other ProcessDifferentMessage().

ProcessMessage() fires fine (before opening AdditionalFunction.java).. but after initiating AdditionalFunction.java by clicking a menubar item, when I try to send a message through the socket which should ONLY fire ProcessDifferentMessage().. it doesn't fire, send it again it fires, send it again it doesnt fire.

When I close the 2nd Jframe and I send message which should fire ProcessDifferentMessage(), same behavior fires sometimes doesn't fire other times. But at this point, I don't want this tread to even fire ProcessDifferenMessage() because I closed the AdditionalFunction.java frame.

So in a nutshell: I have a main class which creates a thread and gives it a incomingmessagereader runnable. This main class also has GUI, and certain menu items trigger new Jframes. (ie. AdditionalFunction.java which extends JFrame). I pass the  reader/writer created in main class from main class into AdditionalFunction constructor. From additionalFunction.java I create a new thread and give it another incomingmessagereader runnable (different implementation and methods). But i want this second incomingmessagereader runnable to cease reading lines from socket when I close it's original jframe (ie. for the 2nd incomingmessagereader runnable it would be additionalfunction.java).. but even after I close the 2nd jframe.. the thread is still active and reading for messages.

1. Why isn't the 2nd thread going out of scope?
2. How can I force dispose it after closing 2nd window? (i tried windowevent/adapter and destroying the 2nd thread.. didn't work)

Comment: 'Going out of scope' is the wrong term. Variables go out of scope. Threads *exit,* and they do that by leaving their `run()` method, and in no other way (unless they are daemon threads). This may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Are you closing your socket when you close your JFrame?

Comment: I am closing socket when I close MainApp (the main JFrame)